# ssh コマンドで利用する config を指定することはできるか

Tags: ssh, openssh

ssh の設定は普通は `~/.ssh/config` に記載されますが、プロジェクトごとに config を特殊化して使いたい場合などがあります。

### 質問:

ssh は普通に実行すると、 `~/.ssh/config` が利用されますが、これ以外の場所に config を作成して、実行時にコマンドラインからこの別 config を読み込むように指定することはできますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

manで確認したところ以下の記載がありました。

```
 -F configfile
         Specifies an alternative per-user configuration file.  If a configuration file is given on the command line, the system-wide configuration file
         (/etc/ssh/ssh_config) will be ignored.  The default for the per-user configuration file is ~/.ssh/config.
```

コマンドラインからユーザごとの設定を指定するのであれば-Fオプションで可能です。

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSH 7.3 より `ssh_config` に導入された `Include` キーワードを利用してはどうでしょうか。

プロジェクトごとに config ファイルを分割、それらを `~/.ssh/config` 内でまとめて読み込めば目的は果たせるかと思います。

```
# 記述例
# ファイル名には HOME `~` やワイルドカード `*` が指定可能
Include config_localnet
Include ~/path/to/ssh_config_*

Host example
    HostName example.com
    Include configs/example
```